# How to skip if no entry in cell, then next x

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This code sends email. In the list sometimes a new employee does not have an email address yet. How can I skip creating an email if the `.To` in Cells(x,2) is blank and go to the `Next x`?

```vb
    With OutMail
        .To = Cells(x, 2)
        .Subject = Cells(x, 3)
        'Change Body for email message here
        .Body = "Dear " & EmployeeName & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Attached is a copy of your check stub for this week." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Thank you," & vbNewLine & _
          "Moe Ballout"
                
        'Check if Attachment file exists, if not, then it will skip email
        If Dir(filename, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add (filename)
            '.Display
            .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts(fromaccount)
            .Send
        End If

    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Len(Cells(x, 2)) > 0 Then
  'your code that creates OutMail object
End If
```